# Supporting videos in all browsers?

Tags: html, video, cross-browser

I built a website that utilizes a background video (.mp4) and have just realized that it sometimes won't play in certain browsers. I was wondering if there is a way I can add supporting file types so if one doesn't display, the next one will be playing instead.

I have the video in 3 file formats (.ogg/.ogv?), (.mp4) and (.webm) which, looking at [caniuse](http://www.caniuse.com) seems that between the 3, will all be supported. My question is, can I just add the video into the html as another source to accomplish this 'fail safe' approach I'm going after?

This is how I have my video player set up:

```
<video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
   <source src="" type="video/mp4" width="1024" height="768" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
</video>
<div class="poster hidden">
   <img src="" alt="">
</div>
```

I use the `video` tag with the `source` attribute to load in the video and a .png for a poster in case the user is in mobile, can I just add 2 more `video` tags with each different `source`, or is there a more elegant way to accomplish this?

Like this:

```
<source src="" type="video/ogv" width="1024" height="768" />
<source src="" type="video/webm" width="1024" height="768" />
```

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a single video tag and multiple source tags. The browser will choose the proper source.

Ex:

```
<video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
    <source src="vid.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="1024" height="768" />
    <source src="vid.ogv" type="video/ogv" width="1024" height="768" />
    <source src="vid.webm" type="video/webm" width="1024" height="768" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
</video>
```

Comment: Excellent, I will try this as soon as I get home! Appreciate the insight and quick response!

Comment: You may want to test thoroughly with different browsers. When I had a similar issue, I found that some browsers do not try all sources until they find one that works for them, but they fail if they don't like the top one.

Comment: @MrLister Could you add the browser(s) that had issues with the above? I've used that code with Chrome, FF, IE, Opera, and Safari without issue.

Comment: @j08691 Unfortunately, I can't find the browsers and/or OSs where it goes wrong now, but you'll have to believe me that I did test at one time and I found that `audio` elements where the `.mp3` source was before the `.ogg` source did not work everywhere, while the other way around (first the `.ogg` source, then the `.mp3`) worked fine.

Comment: @MrLister - I don't doubt you, I just would've liked to add a note explicitly listing the problematic browsers. I'm wondering if this is more of an issue with audio and not video as well.

Comment: I believe i had an issue with webm on a particular version of safari, but approaching this issue again i will add an update.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am not that late. Here is the solution I got, I tested it in Chrome, Firefox, Microsoft Edge, Opera Mini, and Internet Explora. It Works in all

```
<video controls width="250">
    <source src="/media/examples/flower.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
</video>
```

Enjoy!